# Memory leak retaining loss graphs?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have been training a deep NN for days now and all of a sudden I'm out of memory. I'm thinking it is retaining the loss tensors, but retain_graph is not specified and it looks like it defaults to False. I have also looked into .detach but I'm not sure if I put it in the right spot. I'm getting OOM on this line:
*scaler.scale(loss_gen_all).backward()*

And here is the code for the generator, the discriminator is similar.

```
  # Generator
  y_d_hat_r, y_d_hat_g, fmap_r, fmap_g = net_d(y, y_hat)
  with autocast(enabled=False):
    loss_dur = torch.sum(l_length.float())
    loss_mel = F.l1_loss(y_mel, y_hat_mel) * hps.train.c_mel
    loss_kl = kl_loss(z_p, logs_q, m_p, logs_p, z_mask) * hps.train.c_kl

    loss_fm = feature_loss(fmap_r, fmap_g)
    loss_gen, losses_gen = generator_loss(y_d_hat_g)
    loss_gen_all = loss_gen + loss_fm + loss_mel + loss_dur + loss_kl
optim_g.zero_grad()
**scaler.scale(loss_gen_all).backward()**
scaler.unscale_(optim_g)
grad_norm_g = commons.clip_grad_value_(net_g.parameters(), None)
scaler.step(optim_g)
scaler.update()
```

Can I delete the loss tensors and continue training? Can I check if I'm actually storing them? Can I revert an epoch and stop storing them?

Comment: Why the extra indent at the top? Is it inside a loop?

Comment: Inside a function. Full code can be seen here: https://github.com/jaywalnut310/vits/blob/main/train.py